# Spark-Cassandra , How to get data based on Query

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I have a Cassandra table which is quite huge and right now I have spark-Cassandra connection with the following code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pyspark import *
import os
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext


os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages  com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.12:3.0.1 --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=127.0.0.1 pyspark-shell'
conf = SparkConf().set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1").set("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "9042").setAppName("Sentinel").setMaster("spark://Local:7077")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

table_df = sqlContext.read\
        .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")\
        .options(table='movies', keyspace='movie_lens')\
        .load()\
```

The primary key is Movie_id which is an integer.
the .load() loads the entire table into memory, this I want to avoid. One way that i got is to use filter

```
table_df = sqlContext.read\
        .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")\
        .options(table='movies', keyspace='movie_lens')\
        .load()\
        .filter("movie_id = 37032")
```

But does filter actually prevent loading entire table to memory? or does it first load and then filter.
Also, I have to query for many ID's. lets say I need 1000 ID's and each day ID's keep changing . Then how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Spark Cassandra Connector will perform so-called "predicate pushdown" if you're doing the query on the partition key, and will load data only from specific query (the `.load` function will just load the metadata, actual data load will happen first time when you really need data to perform an action). There are [well documented](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/b2.5/doc/14_data_frames.md#full-list-of-predicate-pushdown-restrictions) rules on when predicate pushdown happens in Spark Cassandra connector.  You can also check this by running `table_df.explain()`, and look for `PushedFilters` part for filters marked with asteric `*`.

If you need to lookup multiple IDs, then you can either use `.isin` filter, but it's really not recommended with Cassandra.  It's better to create a dataframe with IDs, and perform so-called [Direct Join](http://www.russellspitzer.com/2018/05/23/DSEDirectJoin/) with Cassandra dataframe (it's available since SCC 2.5 for dataframes, or earlier for RDDs).  I have a [lengthy blog post](https://alexott.blogspot.com/2020/07/spark-effective-joins-with-cassandra.html) on the joining with data in Cassandra

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the quick response. I just have a follow up question. Could you just let me know what is the difference between .filter() and .where() ?? From what I saw they kind of do the same thing.

Comment: no differences between them, just same functions - for historical reasons